# How to plot 3D data aesthetically?

Tags: r, plot

I have 3 dimensional data and need to plot this data in two ways.
The first one should look like this:
[image]

And the second one like this:

[image]

where the given data is more like the second plot.
I do know that both plots have completely different styles and therefore it seems not likely to create it in the same way. Right now I am working with R and Im familiar with packages like ggplot2, plotly or rayshader. But I'm not very familiar with creating more aesthetic and less scientific plots like displayed above. Especially the second one seems beyond the capabilities of R.

I would be very grateful if you could give me tips on how to plot 3-dimensional data in this way. Not necessarily by using R.

Thanks!

Comment: This forum is more oriented toward specific questions that demonstrate that you have started working on your problem (eg by searching online and trying code) and have a specific obstacle to overcome. One place to look: https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/

Comment: As I said, I know plotly but the posted picture seems to differ from what I was able to produce in the past. For example the grid on the surface which is not the same as contour levels. Also the gradient color is quite different from what I know as it develops in two dimensions? Or maybe I’m wrong there, but I only figured out how to specify a gradient by using min and max values.

Answer (score 2):

The second plot type is straightforward in base R:

```r
par(bg = 'black')
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
persp(volcano, box = FALSE, col = 'black', border = 'gray90',
      theta = 45)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, never noticed this function!